# merge sort 1 array and for each change it must effect another list

Tags: python, linked-list, mergesort

I have 2 arrays:

```
dates=[datetime.date(2015, 1, 28), datetime.date(2016, 5, 10), datetime.date(2016, 3, 15), datetime.date(2018, 10, 28), datetime.date(2017, 7, 1), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29)] 
prices=[100, 150, 25, 150, 300, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
```

I need to sort date, but the indexes of the 2 lists need to be linked; i.e for each change I make to dates I must do for prices.

The output expected is

```
dates=[datetime.date(2015, 1, 28), datetime.date(2016, 5, 10), datetime.date(2016, 3, 15), datetime.date(2018, 10, 28), datetime.date(2017, 7, 1), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29), datetime.date(2018, 10, 29)]

prices=[100, 150, 25, 150, 300, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
```

I am currently using a bubble sort but that is too slow for my needs.

Comment: `dates, prices = zip(*sorted(zip(dates, prices)))`

Comment: I suggest combining the two lists into a single list. When you have related data, they should be in a class or a dictionary. Then you can sort the entire data with a single function call.

Comment: first off this is a great solution and i hate not knowing about it but i really need it a merge sort algorithm to do this

Comment: @LukaBediashvili you mean you have to write the mergesort yourself?

Comment: @SilverSlash yes for collage i will but i have no idea how to do this kind of sort

Comment: You write mergesort the way you would and pass in `zip(dates, prices)` as the input data list. There's nothing more to it.

Comment: @SilverSlash but i still need to take the len of the zip and zip has no len i have a merge sort algorithm that sorts one array and needs its len

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easiest to store the original locations:

```
new_dates=[]
indices=[]
for i, date in sorted(enumerate(dates), key = lambda x: x[1]):
    new_dates.append(date)
    indices.append(i)
new_prices=[]
for i, price in sorted(enumerate(prices), key = lambda x: indices.index(x[0]):
    new_prices.append(price)
```